# How to properly perform zonal statistics with overlapping geometries

Tags: python, rasterstats, overlapping-features

I am using python 3.9.

I have a shapefile with overlapping polygons and a raster dataset. I would like to summarize some statistics on my polygons. However, as I mentioned, my polygons are overlapping. I would like to "ignore" these overlapping in the following sense: if I have a polygon that partly overlaps with another, I would like the zonal statistics to apply to the entire polygon -both to the part that is overlapped by another and the part that is not. In other words, I would like to treat each polygon independently, regardless of whether it overlaps by another polygon or not.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from pyproj import CRS
import rasterio
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
from rasterio.mask import mask

polygons = gpd.read_file(data_directory + 'GridCells/ccode_GID.shp')
raster = rasterio.open(tif_file)

raster_array, raster_transform = mask(raster, shapes=polygons.geometry, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)

zs1 = zonal_stats(polygons, raster_array[0], affine=raster_transform, stats=['sum'], nodata=np.nan)
polygons['value'] = [x['sum'] for x in zs1]
```

However, if I am not wrong, this method assumes non-overlapping polygons. Some suggestions to deal with small raster cells overlapping the same polygon is
exactextract (https://github.com/isciences/exactextract), but it does not answer my problem. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source, the vector features are *not* dissolved or otherwise modified. Stats are extracted from each individual feature regardless of whether they happen to overlap, which seems to be what you're asking for.

It's just a loop over each feature which yields the stats from said feature:

https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/blob/5dac003081e8af906cf60494522f2fd3459d0896/src/rasterstats/main.py#L164

`read_features()` is not modifying the features in any way.